# How to combines two nested data structures into one?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I need to definite a method that combines two nested data structures into one.

here is the first hash:

```
[
  {
     "blake" => {
       :awesomeness => 10,
       :height => "74",
       :last_name => "johnson"
     },
      "ashley" => {
        :awesomeness => 9,
        :height => 60,
        :last_name => "dubs"
     }
   }
]
```

here is the second hash:

```
[
   {
     :first_name => "blake"
   },
   {
     :first_name => "ashley"
   }
]
```

the result will be like this:

```
[
   {
      :first_name => "blake",
      :awesomeness => 10,
      :height => "74",
      :last_name => "johnson"
   },
   {
      :first_name => "ashley",
      :awesomeness => 9,
      :height => 60,
      :last_name => "dubs"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that what you call hashes are indeed arrays, and that too they are not consistent.  First one is an array containing single hash, and second one is an array containing two hashes.

For the given two arrays, if we call the first `v1` and second one `v2`, then, below code should give the output you desire:

```
v1[0].values.map.with_index {|v, i| v2[i].merge(v)}
```

---

**Explanation:**

[`Hash#merge`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) merges two hashes, so it has to be used to achieve the result.

The first hash will be from `v1` - we pick the first element of `v1` array, which is a hash, and take all its `values` which are hashes themselves - thus, we have an array of hash in `v1[0].values`.

The second array of hashes is `v2`.

Now, we use the [`Enumerable#map`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method to iterate over first array of hashes and collecting the result of merging each of its elements with corresponding element from `v2`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant to define the following hash (rather than an array containing one element, a hash).

```
h = { "blake" =>  { :awesomeness => 10,
                    :height => "74",
                    :last_name => "johnson"
                  },
      "ashley" => { :awesomeness => 9,
                    :height => 60,
                    :last_name => "dubs"
                  }
    }
```

There are many ways to add the key-value pairs `:first_name=>"blake"` and `:first_ame=>"ashley"` to their associated hashes. Here is one:

```
 f = h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = { :first_name => k }.merge(v) }
   #=> {"blake" =>{:first_name=>"blake",
   #               :awesomeness=>10,
   #               :height=>"74",
   #               :last_name=>"johnson"},
   #    "ashley"=>{:first_ame=>"ashley",
   #               :awesomeness=>9,
   #               :height=>60,
   #               :last_name=>"dubs"}}
```

So this begs the question: what is the function of the following array?

```
a = [{ :first_name => "blake" }, { :first_name => "ashley" }]
```

If this array is used to specify which keys of `f` are to be retained, we could write

```
retain = a.map { |g| g[:name] } 
  #=> ["blake", "ashley"] 
f.select { |k| retain.include?(k) }
  #=> {"blake"=>{:first_name=>"blake", :awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74",
  #              :last_name=>"johnson"},
  #    "ashley"=>{:first_name=>"ashley", :awesomeness=>9, :height=>60,
  #               :last_name=>"dubs"}}
```

On the other hand, if

```
a = [{:name=>"blake"}]
```

then

```
retain = a.map { |g| g[:name] } 
  #=> ["blake"] 
f.select { |k| retain.include?(k) }
  #=> {"blake"=>{:first_name=>"blake", :awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74",
  #              :last_name=>"johnson"}}
```